# Negating off-diagonal blocks retains positive-semidefiniteness?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices

I am trying to follow some notes that state
$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
A&B^T\\B&C
\end{bmatrix}
\succeq 0
\Longleftrightarrow
M'=
\begin{bmatrix}
A&-B^T\\-B&C
\end{bmatrix}
\succeq 0$$
and I want to prove this to myself (just the $\Rightarrow$ direction because it's trivial to go the other way once one direction is proven).

Clearly, $
\begin{bmatrix}
A&B^T\\B&C
\end{bmatrix}
\succeq 0\Longrightarrow A,C\succeq0
$
 by computing $x^TMx$ (for $x=\begin{bmatrix}v\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\v\end{bmatrix}$) which is $\geq0\ \ \forall\ v$ by definition.

Then for a general $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1^T&x_2^T
\end{bmatrix}
M
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\underbrace{x_1^TAx_1}_{\geq0}
+
\underbrace{x_2^TCx_2}_{\geq0}
+2x_2^TBx_1\geq2x_2^TBx_1
$$

and

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1^T&x_2^T
\end{bmatrix}
M'
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2
\end{bmatrix}
=x_1^TAx_1+x_2^TCx_2-2x_2^TBx_1\geq-2x_2^TBx_1.
$$

Then I get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply your assumption on $M$ to the vector $[-x_1^T,x_2^T]$.